# Button Clicked true or false - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, buttonclick

I am a Bit Beginner In JavaScript. So I need a code about { If we clicked a button a function need to run} more of them suggested this but it still not working ! and I don`t know why? Can you solve it?

```js
if(document.getElementById("btn").clicked == true){
//some code here
    console.log("working");
}
```

```html
<button id=""btn>ClickEvent</button>
```

Comment: You made a typo on `id=""btn` => `id="btn"`

Comment: oh ! that`s not a problem ! i have wrongly typed here but in my main code i have typed correctly!. Problem : {If i clicked it does not printing it in console}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use the if. `if` statement is executed on page load.

Instead, use `Onclick()` for example :

```js
var data = "";

function clickBtn() {
  if(data != "")
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Hello World !";
  else
    getData();
}

function getData() {
    data = "Hello World !";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="clickBtn()">Click me</button>

<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: The Whole If Statement Would Remains In a function() But I need to use the function twice example {Using It first time to store a value from another function() , then i need to use the value when the person click the button } If You understand please make me way to it.

Comment: Ok wait ! i am making my main code small and placing it  here                                                                       function clickevent(a){
 //getting the value of [a] first .
    if(document.getElementById("eq").clicked == true){
     //then using the value of [a] in second 
    var b = Number(document.getElementById("textbox").value);
    var output = a+b;
    console.log(output);

 }
}

Answer (score 1):

Good question, lets use the an HTML file that references a JavaScript.

So the first file lets call it **webpage.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 

<input type="button" value="save" onclick="save()"></input>

<input type="button" value="display" onclick="print()"></input>

<div id="area"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the second file **script.js**

```
function save()
{

StringTest="Hello world";

}


function print()
{

document.getElementById("area").innerHTML=StringTest;

}
```

The approach might be a little different but this is recommended as you would more control over the elements in the script.

For example: 
`<input type="button"` will tell the script that it is a form input of the type button whose click will call the function `print()` in the JavaScript

`document.getElementById("area")`captures the elements that we define from the Document Object Model(DOM)

Comment: Program[]                                                []Wait I am Explaining It Clearly ! . First Think That {You have Inputted A Number [Example : 10] .Now Think Again ,There Is Two Button ..  1st button`s Work is [click to forward the inputted number to a function called (Run) ] and 2nd Button`s work is [run the function called (Run)] [][][][][][][]Action [We Need To Do] [][][] So whenever we pressed the button 1.it need to store it in a function Run//only storing it not to run the full function of Run.next whenever we pressed the button 2.it need to run the function Run

Comment: @ManojWarWay I edited my answer
First Button: Saves the Value
Second button: Prints the Value

Comment: oh thanks ! this what i needed .Thank You Very Much.